# Search in PHP same result displays many times?

Tags: php, sql, search, select

I am using an SQL query in PHP for searching:

```
SELECT *
FROM vendor, branches
WHERE branches.vendor_id = vendor.vendor_id
AND vendor.name LIKE '%".$query."%'
OR vendor.description LIKE '%".$query."%'
OR branches.city LIKE '%".$query."%'
```

It displays the result multiple times. I want PHP to display the result, if found, only one time, and not multiple times.

Comment: Are all the results the same, or does the query return multiple different rows?

Comment: query return multiple different rows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
SELECT * FROM vendor INNER JOIN branches ON branches.vendor_id = vender.vendor_id
WHERE (
    vendor.name LIKE '%".$query."%'
    OR vendor.description LIKE '%".$query."%'
    OR branches.city LIKE '%".$query."%'
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try select distinct or use a group by. You can use the query below, also if you are using distinct or group by try using one element, e.g. SELECT id instead of SELECT *.

```
SELECT * FROM vendor as VTable 
WHERE vendor.name LIKE '%".$query."%' 
AND VTable.vendor_id = (SELECT TOP 1 FROM branches as BTable WHERE BTable.vendor_id = VTable.vendor OR BTable.city LIKE '%".$query."%')
OR vendor.description LIKE '%".$query."%'
```

Comment: I also try this also but it also display same result as I mentioned above

Answer (score 0):

More descriptively,
1. SELECT DISTINCT column_1(, column_2, etc) FROM table_name
2. SELECT * FROM table_name GROUP  BY column_1(, column_2)